# Jenkins with msbuild for .net application

Tags: model-view-controller, jenkins, msbuild, couchbase

I am trying to build my MVC application in jenkins using MSBuild. It is giving some errors giving in the screenshot.

Comment: You did not attach the screen shot.

Comment: You can temporarly remove the "jenkins" part from the equation.  Go to your build server...find the place where the source code downloaded...and manually run msbuild.exe against your .sln or .csproj (or other)........then trouble shoot.  Missing references is a common error.